# Shouldn't all questions with the Vimperator tag be on Super User?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed the tag [vimperator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vimperator), a program which I find interesting. But I always thought questions regarding the program were out of the scope of SO. Am I wrong about this?

If that is the case should the tag even exist?

Comment: If they aren't questions "unique to software development" then all your base don't belong to SO.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be aimed mainly towards developers, so questions *may* be [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) under the *"software tools commonly used by programmers"* guideline. They also have to be *"a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"*.

Quoting [the Firefox Add-on page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/vimperator/):

> But Vimperator is more than just a simple command interface to Firefox — it is a complete development environment as well. If you are a web developer, you can enjoy an interactive JavaScript shell — even with completion support. Or if you want to extend Vimperator, you can easily do that by just dropping a JavaScript file in its plugin directory.

So it doesn't mean that all questions are automatically on-topic, they should still be judged individually. But the tag in itself is fine.

Comment: ah, didn't consider that aspect of it!